# Using Cardslib: "CardView cannot be cast to CardNativeView"

Tags: android, github, classcastexception, android-cardview, cardslib

i just implemented [Cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) in my code.

I'm using the following code to implement TopColoredCard:

```
ArrayList<Card> cards = initCard();
updateAdapter(cards);    

...

private ArrayList<Card> initCard() {
    //Init an array of Cards
    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < AppData.mTitles.length; i++) {
        TopColoredCard card = new TopColoredCard(getApplicationContext());
        card.setColorResourceId(AppData.mColors[i]);
        card.setTitleOverColor(AppData.mTitles[i]);
        card.setSubTitleOverColor(subTitle(i));
        cards.add(card);
    }
    return cards;
}
```

And implemented:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.0.1'
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-recyclerview:2.0.1'
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-cards:2.0.1'
```

It works well on Android 5.0 and higher.
On lower Versions I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView cannot be cast to it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative
        at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.cards.topcolored.TopColoredCard.setupInnerViewElements(TopColoredCard.java:206)
        at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.Card.getInnerView(Card.java:293)
        at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView.setupMainView(CardView.java:379)
        at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView.buildUI(CardView.java:282)
        at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView.setCard(CardView.java:242)
        at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.recyclerview.internal.BaseRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(BaseRecyclerViewAdapter.java:124)
        at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.recyclerview.internal.BaseRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(BaseRecyclerViewAdapter.java:38)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4138)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3448)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1306)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:561)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
```

I think it is a bug of the lib, because it works on API lvl. 20 but it doesn't work on lower version.

Maybe anyone of you can help me.

Lucas :)

//EDIT:
This is my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/background_material_light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_actionbar">
        <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.recyclerview.view.CardRecyclerView"
            android:id="@+id/recycler" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also post your CardListView in layout file as well?

Answer (score 1):

Change your class from CardView to CardNativeView in your xml file.